# Trouble Using a Function

Tags: powerquery, m

I'm trying to invoke a function that sorts a column in the calling query's table.

I'm basically trying to turn this...

[image]

...into this...

[image]

I made this simple function:

```
= () => let
    Source = Table1,
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(Source,{{"MatchedWords", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

...which works basically fine when invoked manually. *Except* it creates an entirely new table with the result each time it is run. *What I want it to do is to perform the sort in the original calling query's table.*

Also, when I try to invoke this function from within the calling query's table, Power Query balks due to a circular reference.

What am I doing wrong? How can I use a function to make the sort changes occur to the columns within the calling query's table, and how should I actually call the function?

P.S. I know there are easier ways to do the sort. The sort isn't my real goal. I'm just using the sort as a "simplified" example of a similar requirement that I'm addressing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is referencing objects outside the scope of the query, which is generally not a good idea. Instead, all information required from outside, should be passed as parameters.

You may change your function to:

```
(MyTable as table, MyColumn as text) => 
let
    Source = MyTable,
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(Source,{{MyColumn, Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

This function (I called it Sort) can be called from inside your query:

```
let
    Source = Table1,
    Sorted = Sort(Source, "MatchedWords")
in
    Sorted
```

Note that Power Query uses the concept of immutability, meaning that no values are ever changed, only new values are added. E.g. within the query above, you have the original table in Source and a new, sorted table in Sorted. Outside the query, only the sorted version can be referenced (by the name of the query).

Comment: Thanks @MarcelBeug. To make sure I understand: Because of the immutability, I cannot actually call the Sort function from within the original query table (Table1)? Rather, I must call the function from within a second query table, which references Table1 as its source?

Comment: You CAN call the Sort function from within your Table1 query. Not by referring to Table1, but by referring to the previous step inside your query. Suppose my example query above is called Table2, then it's working fine but it would produce a circular reference if the second step would be: Sorted = Sort(Table2, "MatchedWords")

Comment: I got it working. My previous last step in my Table1 query (before the `in`) was labeled `#"Removed Duplicates"`, so I added `Sorted = Sort(#"Removed Duplicates", "MatchedWords")` before the `in` and replaced `in #"Removed Duplicates"` with `in Sorted`. I _definitely_ appreciate your assistance!